# True or false? Then $x_n/y_n$ $\rightarrow$ 0.

Tags: analysis

Suppose that {$x_n$} is bounded, $y_n$>0 for all n, and $y_n$ $\rightarrow$ + $\infty$

True or false? Then $x_n/y_n$ $\rightarrow$ 0.

This is what I have:

Given $\big\{x_n\big\}$ is bounded, let $\epsilon>$0 there $\exists$ $M>0$, M$\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ st $|x_n|\leq$ M $\forall$ n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$. Then, $\frac{\epsilon}{M}$>0 and $\exists$ $M_0$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ st $|\frac{1}{y_n}|<$ $\frac{\epsilon}{M}$ for all n $\geq$ $M_0$. Then $|\frac{x_n}{y_n}-0|$= $|\frac{x_n}{y_n}|$ $\leq$ $\frac{M}{|y_n|}$ =$\frac{M}{|y_n|}$ < M* $\frac{\epsilon}{M}$. Divide out the M and $\frac{M}{|y_n|}$ <     $\epsilon$ when n $\geq$ $m_0$. Therefore, $|\frac{x_n}{y_n}-0|$ < $\epsilon$ $\forall$  n $\geq$ $m_0$. So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ =0 meaning $\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ $\rightarrow$ 0. Therefore, the statement is true.

Would this be correct or do I have errors? if I have errors how do I fix it?

Comment: Huh?  What are the hypotheses?

Comment: OP this is written quite unclearly.

Comment: you don't tell us what xn or yn are

Comment: It is fixed... sorry